# getChangedCells is returning [object, Object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with edit cell options. Both methods getRowData and getChangedCells returning  [object, Object]. Please help what could be problem.

Comment: Can you post some code, or a link to a site?

Answer (score 0):

It's real hard to know. But when you get an [object, Object] (guessing in a alert) you should use debugger (like firebug) to inspect the object returned.

Please be more specific. And show some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look into the result of:

```
jQuery("#grid").getRowData();
```

I would suggest including the jQuery [JSON library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and calling:

```
alert(jQuery.toJSON(jQuery("#grid").getRowData()));
```

This will display all of the contents of an object exactly as it exists in your grid.  Just make sure that you replace "#grid" with the identifier for your grid.